# MySQL query - Multiple sums across multiple tables, need to ignore null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the below SUM of thumbsup minus thumbsdown from 5 different tables and then SUM all these values together, which it works if all 'commthumbs' returns a row, but if one or more of the 'commthumbs' have no rows then it returns a null value. I have tried using IFNULL as shown in the first LEFT JOIN below as an example. I have also tried ISNULL and COALESCE in place of IFNULL but still can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

```
    SELECT 
        user.userID, user.username,
        SUM(a.commthumbs+b.commthumbs+c.commthumbs+d.commthumbs) AS 'commthumbs', 
        e.fixthumbs AS 'fixthumbs'
    FROM
        user

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, IFNULL(SUM(gameCommThUp-gameCommThDown),0) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM
        gamecomm
        GROUP BY userID) a ON a.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(fixCommThUp-fixCommThDown) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM 
        fixcomm
        GROUP BY userID) b ON b.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(replyCommThUp-replyCommThDown) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM gamereply
        GROUP BY userID) c ON c.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT userID, SUM(fixReplyThUp-fixReplyThDown) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM fixreply
        GROUP BY userID) d ON d.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(fixThUp-fixThDown) AS 'fixthumbs'
        FROM 
        fix
        GROUP BY userID) e ON e.userID = user.userID

    WHERE user.userID = 2;
```

Comment: Can you try like this :  SUM(IFNULL(gameCommThUp,0)-IFNULL(gameCommThDown,0)) in all your join

Comment: You're IFNULLing the SUM - which as you've highlighted returns null if any of the values are null.  As  per comment above, you need to IFNULL the value before you sum it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  SELECT 
        user.userID, user.username,
        SUM(IFNULL(a.commthumbs,0)+IFNULL(b.commthumbs,0)+IFNULL(c.commthumbs,0)+IFNULL(d.commthumbs,0)) AS 'commthumbs', 
        IFNULL(e.fixthumbs,0) AS 'fixthumbs'
    FROM
        user

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(IFNULL(gameCommThUp,0)-IFNULL(gameCommThDown,0)) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM
        gamecomm
        GROUP BY userID) a ON a.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(IFNULL(fixCommThUp,0)-IFNULL(fixCommThDown,0)) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM 
        fixcomm
        GROUP BY userID) b ON b.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(IFNULL(replyCommThUp,0)-IFNULL(replyCommThDown,0)) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM gamereply
        GROUP BY userID) c ON c.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT userID, SUM(IFNULL(fixReplyThUp,0)-IFNULL(fixReplyThDown,0)) AS 'commthumbs'
        FROM fixreply
        GROUP BY userID) d ON d.userID = user.userID

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        userID, SUM(IFNULL(fixThUp,0)-IFNULL(fixThDown,0)) AS 'fixthumbs'
        FROM 
        fix
        GROUP BY userID) e ON e.userID = user.userID

    WHERE user.userID = 2;
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I'm still receiving a null value

Comment: Given sql query should work, please share the sample data to test it

Comment: I just noticed that you added the IFNULL to the SUM within the first SELECT statement also, so I tried that and it worked. Thanks so much!